# Remote connection from Ubuntu to Ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

This may be very trivial for most of ubuntu experts; but, I am still to figure out how to do this  as I am quite new to Linux / Ubuntu.

I would like to have graphical connection just like chrome- remote desktop offers for window. I know that chrome remote desktop is also supporting linux; but, I could not make it work.

Team viewer is not preferred. A couple of years, Teamviewer refused to make connection claiming that I was making commercial use of "personal copy". Though this was not the case, I was connecting very frequently to my office computer and working from home.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly you want to do. What kind of connection do you need? Command line? Graphical? Do you only want to copy files? Have you tried googling "remote desktop ubuntu"?

Comment: @terdon Question modified as you suggested.

Comment: I have used Chrome Remote Desktop for Ubuntu to Ubuntu remote access. It works for me. Have you tried using it within the same network? Which versions of Ubuntu are you using at each end? Are they both running Unity? Are you running the latest stable version of Chrome on both machines?

Comment: Well, there is Remmina

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for a graphical remote session would be to set up a VNC server as outlined [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers) in the wiki

Comment: Thanks, I configured vino. But, how could I connect from other ubuntu?

Comment: Install [one of these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Clients) and connect to the remote computer using its IP address (or its private IP if you are on the same LAN)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Teamviewer, easy and works great with Ubuntu.

http://www.teamviewer.com/sv/download/linux.aspx

Comment: Team viewer is not preferred. A couple of years, Teamviewer refused to make connection claiming that I was making commercial use of "personal copy". Though this was not the case, I was connecting very frequently to my office computer and working from home.

Comment: Sounds commercial to me, but I agree.  TeamViewer is closed and no sense in using it especially since it isn't as efficient as other methods.